# React-Native ref of child component for drop down

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-dropdown and I am having trouble getting reference of components within a listview component.  As I am adding the drop down to the listview rows so I need   to assign ref to select component within it but the reference is returning undefined as only top level view components can be used with ref.  Is there a possible solution.  Please help. The code is as follows:

In the main render:

```
<ListView ref='listView'
   style = {{ backgroundColor: '#EAEAEC'}}
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   renderRow={this.renderRow} />
```

In render row:

```
<View style={{flex:2.5, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Select
       width={250}
       ref="SELECT1"
       optionListRef={() => {this._getOptionList()}}
       defaultValue="Select a Province in Canada ..."
       onSelect={ (index) => {console.log(index, 'is selected.');} }>
       <Option>Alberta</Option>
       <Option>British Columbia</Option>
       <Option>Manitoba</Option>
       <Option>Yukon</Option>
    </Select>
  <OptionList ref="OPTIONLIST"/>
</View>
```

Now, I need to assign the OptionList tag with ref `OPTIONLIST` to optionListRef attribute of select but as this is not top level view so `this.refs["OPTIONLIST"]` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: I suspect you don't need the ref, and instead you should define your callback functions within the closure of each child in the loop that's outputting them.  If you include some code I can be more specific, but see this example: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: @AdamTerlson I have added the code please check.

Answer (score 1):

`renderRow` is given `rowData` as a parameter (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html).

Within that function, redefine all your inline arrow functions to pass this rowData on to the common handler.

Example:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
    ...
    optionListRef={() => this._getOptionList(rowData)}
},

_getOptionList(rowData) {
   // Use rowData
}
```

As a side note, you don't need the curly braces in arrow functions unless it's multi-line.